# Unable to save a Category/incorrect information stored

Tags: admin, category

Magento 2.4.2

I am having some rather odd errors when saving a new Category or updating an existing one. I have save one called "Rooty Root" which does not show up in the tree:
[image: Saved category not in the tree]

I have been able to get another root category to show up by altering the "path" in the "catalog_category_entity" table but this isn't really a viable option. It appears that the "path" hidden input is empty when the page is loaded which I guess explains why this would be the case, however the "parent" is set correctly.

Additionally, the url key is updated but it creates/updates a URL Rewrite targeting the homepage:
[image: image showing the empty Request Path for the category]

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is clearly the 'work' of a customization somewhere, so I would advise checking your custom code and 3rd party integration and see which one causes this issue.

By default, you should be able to add as many root categories as you want in the admin panel. Ref: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/category-root.html

Comment: Going through my plugins one by one eventually yielded a result. After much head scratching I can see where the error is, I wonder if they even tested this module... Thanks!

Comment: no problem, anytime! sorry to hear about the trouble, unfortunately, there are many modules out there with insufficient QA.